# How to calculate this limit?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

For didactic purposes I study the function

$$f(x):=\lim\limits_{k\to \infty} \frac{x^{2k}+\left(\frac \pi 3\right)^{2k}}{x^{2k-1}+\left(\frac \pi 3\right)^{2k-1}}$$

with help of Mathematica. Everything is fine, except for the case

```
DiscreteLimit[(x^(2 k) + (Pi/3)^(2 k))/(x^(2 k - 1) + (Pi/3)^(2 k - 
   1)), k -> Infinity, Assumptions -> x < -Pi/3]
```

, where the input is returned in several hours. Is there a way to calculate it with Mathematica?
It's clear the desired result is `x`.

Comment: Using `Limit` and removing the assumption gives `ConditionalExpression[x, Log[3 x] > Log[\[Pi]]]`

Comment: @flinty: Thank you for your interest to the question. The same `DiscreteLimit[(x^(2 k) + (Pi/3)^(2 k))/(x^(2 k - 1) + (Pi/3)^(2 k - 
       1)), k -> Infinity, Assumptions -> x \[Element] Reals]`  does.

Comment: I'd like to add that `DiscreteLimit[(x^(2 k) + (Pi/3)^(2 k))/(x^(2 k - 1) + (Pi/3)^(2 k - 
       1)), k -> Infinity, Assumptions -> x <= 0 && x >= -1]` and `DiscreteLimit[(x^(2 k) + (Pi/3)^(2 k))/(x^(2 k - 1) + (Pi/3)^(2 k - 
       1)), k -> Infinity, Assumptions -> x > -Pi/3 && x <= -1]` work well.

Comment: `Simplify[DiscreteLimit[(x^(2 k) + (Pi/3)^(2 k))/(x^(2 k - 1) + (Pi/3)^(2 k - 1)), k -> Infinity], x < -Pi/3]`

Comment: @BobHanlon: This results in `ConditionalExpression[x, Log[3*x] > Log[Pi]]`, not taking into account `Assumptions -> x < -Pi/3`. Hope you understand this is not it.

Comment: With v12.3.1, I get varying results with different evaluations of either `Simplify[DiscreteLimit[(x^(2 k) + (Pi/3)^(2 k))/(x^(2 k - 1) + (Pi/3)^(2 k - 1)), k -> Infinity], x < -Pi/3]` or using `FullSimplify`. Repeated evaluations give `ConditionalExpression[Pi/3, Log[x] < 0]`.

Comment: @BobHanlon:  Also use 12.3.1. `Log[x]<0` is equivalent to `x>0&&x<1`. The result of `FullSimplify[DiscreteLimit[(x^(2 k) + (Pi/3)^(2 k))/(x^(2 k - 1) + (Pi/3)^(2 k - 1)), k -> Infinity], x < -Pi/3]` also does not answer the question.

Comment: As I said, I don't get consistent results. Evaluating `FullSimplify[
 DiscreteLimit[(x^(2 k) + (Pi/3)^(2 k))/(x^(2 k - 1) + (Pi/3)^(2 k - 1)), k -> Infinity], x < -Pi/3]` just now; I got `ConditionalExpression[Pi/3, 0 < Log[x] < Log[Pi/3]]`

Comment: Can the downvoter ground it? TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Apart` , switch to -x with x>Pi/3 and the fact, that `(-x)^(2 k)` is `x^(2 k)` for k Integers.

```
f1 = (x^(2 k) + (Pi/3)^(2 k))/(x^(2 k - 1) + (Pi/3)^(2 k - 1))

f2 = f1 // Apart

f3 = (f2 - x) /. x -> -x

(*   f4 = f3 /. (-x)^(2 k) -> x^(2 k)
     Limit[f4 /. k -> kk/2, kk -> \[Infinity], 
        Assumptions -> {x > \[Pi]/3}]
   (*   0   *)   
*)
```

**Edit**

With `DiscreteLimit` you need no steps done by hand. You get result for f3

```
DiscreteLimit[f3, k -> Infinity, Assumptions -> x > Pi/3]

(*   0   *)
```

Is makes use of the identity shown in

```
Reduce[{(-x)^(2 k) == (x)^(2 k), x > Pi/3, k>1,k \[Element] Integers}, 
  Reals] // Simplify[#, {x > Pi/3, k > 1, k \[Element] Integers}
] &
```

produces `True`.

Even Limit yields the same (in higher versions).

Comment: Unfortunately, the key step  `(-x)^(2 k) == x^(2 k)` is done by hand and is not correct for negative `x` and positive `k` (think of `x=-3` and `k==3/2`). ` k -> kk/2`  is not necessary since `Limit[f4,k->\[Infinity],Assumptions->{x>\[Pi]/3}]` also produces `0`. I cannot accept it.

Comment: As is wrote " for k Integers"  and "with x>Pi/3" . Is k==3/2 an Integer ???  Is x>Pi/3  negative ???

Comment: You use `Limit` which takes noniteger values of `k` (`kk`) too. Fortunately, both `DiscreteLimit[f4 /. k -> kk/2, kk -> \[Infinity], 
 Assumptions -> {x > \[Pi]/3}]` and `DiscreteLimit[f4, k -> \[Infinity], Assumptions -> {x > \[Pi]/3}]` produce `0`. If you adjust this place, I'll think about  accepting  your answer.

Comment: `Reduce[{(-x)^(2 k) == (x)^(2 k), x > Pi/3, k > 1, 
   k \[Element] Integers}, Reals] // 
 Simplify[#, {x > Pi/3, k > 1, k \[Element] Integers}] & ` yield `True ` thus confirms my key step.

Comment: I'd like to notice that `DiscreteLimit[f3, k -> Infinity, Assumptions -> x > Pi/3]` produces `0`.

Comment: I couldn't do that because my version 8.0 has no `DiscreteLimit ` .

Comment: Can you try it in the cloud? Since `Limit[f3,k->Infinity,Assumptions->x>Pi/3]` performs `0` so does `DiscreteLimit`. Please edit your answer in order I would be able to accept it.

Comment: thanks for the tip !

Comment: To complete your edit, please add `Reduce[{(-x)^(2 k) == (x)^(2 k), x > Pi/3, k > 1,     k \[Element] Integers}, Reals] //   Simplify[#, {x > Pi/3, k > 1, k \[Element] Integers}] & ` which produces `True` to your answer. This is essentially used there.

Answer (score -1):

To simplify the expression, replace 2k by k, Pi/3 by p and divide numerator and denominator by: x^(k-1). This results in:

[image]

Now in, the numerator, factor out x:

[image]

Next call q = p/x:

[image]

As x is a constant, we need to determine the limit of `(1 + (q)^k)/(1 + (q)^(k - 1))`:

```
Limit[(1 + (q)^k)/(1 + (q)^(k - 1)), k -> Infinity]
```

[image]

This means, that a limit exists, `q` must be larger than 1:

```
q= p/x = Pi/(3 x)>1
```

The limit of the simplified expression is `q`. Therefore, the limit of the original expression is `x q` This gives the result:

```
0 < x <Pi/3
limit = Pi/3
```

Comment: -1. Sorry, this is not it. First, your direction " replace 2k by k" and `Limit` instead of `DiscreteLimit` lead to nonequivalent problem: the limit  `Limit[(x^(2 k) + (Pi/3)^(2 k))/(x^(2 k - 1) + (Pi/3)^(2 k -     1)), k -> Infinity, Assumptions -> x < -Pi/3]` does not exist. Second, I don't see any answer to my question in your attempt. I will be waiting for a reach-in-content and serious reply

Comment: Well, you claim a lot without proof . First, we do not have an alternate limit, so replacing 2k by k should no change. Then please proof that the claim that Limit[..] does not exists, I think it is wrong.

Comment: You are right that `Limit[(x^(2 k) + (Pi/3)^(2 k))/(x^(2 k - 1) + (Pi/3)^(2 k -         1)), k -> Infinity, Assumptions -> x < -Pi/3]` exists and I wasn't. Unfortunately, `Limit[(x^(2 k) + (Pi/3)^(2 k))/(x^(2 k - 1) + (Pi/3)^(2 k - 1)), 
 k -> Infinity, Assumptions -> x < -Pi]`  returns the input. I still don't see an answer to my question in your attempt.

Comment: Perhaps you should claim less and try more.  Limit[(x^(2 k) + (Pi/3)^(2 k))/(x^(2 k - 1) + (Pi/3)^(2 k - 1)), k -> Infinity] works fine